# How to use inherited contexts in Go

Tags: go, linter

I am writing an Kubernetes Operator in Go. I am struggling with the clean handling of the given context object. It is a good practice to to pass an inherited context as a parameter to further methods. When doing not so the linter shows the following messages:

```
instance, err := k8sConnector.getInstance(r.ctx, req.NamespacedName)
```

```
root@8794fe3af767:/go/xpro-update-manager# golangci-lint run --timeout=15m  ./...
controllers/release_controller.go:79:43: Non-inherited new context, use function like `context.WithXXX` instead (contextcheck)
        instance, err := k8sConnector.getInstance(r.ctx, req.NamespacedName)
                                                 ^
```

But when doing so (as documented in https://pkg.go.dev/context#WithCancel) the linter shows the same message:

```
    k8sContext, cancel := context.WithCancel(r.ctx)
    defer cancel()

    instance, err := k8sConnector.getInstance(k8sContext, req.NamespacedName)
```

```
root@8794fe3af767:/go/xpro-update-manager# golangci-lint run --timeout=15m  ./...
controllers/xprorelease_controller.go:79:43: Non-inherited new context, use function like `context.WithXXX` instead (contextcheck)
        instance, err := k8sConnector.getInstance(k8sContext, req.NamespacedName)
                                                 ^
```

What is the correct handling of the context object? It seems to me that the linter has a false positive because in my opinion it is indeed a inherited context which I am passing in contrast to what the linter says.

Comment: There are some open [issues](https://github.com/sylvia7788/contextcheck/issues) related to false positive checks. Your solution seems correct.

Comment: This looks like a false positive to me, but a quick scan through the `contextcheck` repo seems to suggest that `context.WithCancel` won't resolve the issue. If you want to suppress this error until the issue is fixed, it looks like you'll want to `context.WtihValue(r.ctx, "tmpKey", "ctxcheck")`. Adding a value, basically... [that's how this check is tested at least](https://github.com/sylvia7788/contextcheck/blob/20c10da9027bad9d852ae23374cb8d25d7ecb745/testdata/src/a/a.go#L27)